# Cannot get .getJSON to fire onclick

Tags: javascript, html, json, onclick

I'm trying to get the "restapp" function to fire onclick, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Restaurant App</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="info" type="button" onclick="restapp()" value="Create Table From JSON">

<hr>
<pre id="demo"></pre>

<script>
result = [];
city = 'chicago';
opURL = 'http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=' + city;

function restapp() {
    $.getJSON(opURL, function(data) {
        //data is the JSON string
        for (i=0; i<data.restaurants.length; i++) {
            result.push("Name: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].name);
                result.push("Address: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].address);
                result.push("Price: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].price);
                result.push("<br>");
            }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an extra ); after result.push("<br>");

Comment: My mistake. That was a typo from when I was formatting the code to post here. It still doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your `JQuery`?

$.getJSON requires JQuery. Check your browser console for error.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Insert this in your `head` tag.

You can use JQuery selector to select your input field and use click method for click event.

Comment: This was it. I completely forgot that!

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

There just seems to be some misplaced function brackets. I've made the innerHTML insert as a successor handler:

```
function restapp() {
    $.getJSON(opURL, function(data) {
        //data is the JSON string
        for (i=0; i<data.restaurants.length; i++) {
            result.push("Name: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].name);
                result.push("Address: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].address);
                result.push("Price: " + 
            data.restaurants[i].price);
                result.push("<br>");
        }
    }).document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);    
}
```